# How to Solve : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: netbeans-8

I tried to make a delete button in netbeans but after successfully deleting, a warning appears. is there any that can?

```
private void jButtonDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:


         int index = jTableSurat.getSelectedRow();
                  // jika tidak ada
             if (index == -1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pilih baris yang akan di-delete!");
                return;// maka proses dibatalkan

                }

             suratmasukkeluardomain suratmasuk=SuratModel.findOne(index);

             SuratService.delete(suratmasuk);
             bersih();
             SuratModel.delete(index);

    }
```

Exception coming:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
    at aplikasisuratmasukkeluar.tabelmodel.suratmasukkeluartabel.findOne(suratmasukkeluartabel.java:67)
    at aplikasisuratmasukkeluar.ui.FormSuratMasuk$1.valueChanged(FormSuratMasuk.java:82)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeIndexInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:677)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableRowsDeleted(JTable.java:4509)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4412)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(AbstractTableModel.java:261)
    at aplikasisuratmasukkeluar.tabelmodel.suratmasukkeluartabel.delete(suratmasukkeluartabel.java:61)
    at aplikasisuratmasukkeluar.ui.FormSuratMasuk.jButtonDeleteActionPerformed(FormSuratMasuk.java:953)
    at aplikasisuratmasukkeluar.ui.FormSuratMasuk.access$3100(FormSuratMasuk.java:43)
    at aplikasisuratmasukkeluar.ui.FormSuratMasuk$12.actionPerformed(FormSuratMasuk.java:651)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at com.jtattoo.plaf.BaseButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You need to show the code for suratmasukkeluartabel.findOne() since that is where the error is.  The code you provided doesn't seem to be related.  That code calls get() on an ArrayList with -1 as the parameter.

Comment: public suratmasukkeluardomain findOne(int index){
        return listOfsuratmasukdomain.get(index);
    }

Comment: Can you check/show the code that calls it, which is FormSuratMasuk$1.valueChanged(FormSuratMasuk.java:82) and passes the -1 index. This is not the code above, which is for a different function.

Comment: thank you, my problem has been resolved for your help